# how can i read properties file in jsp using html5

Tags: html, jsp, properties

Can anyone give the solution for reading .properties file from jsp page (using HTML5 or other tags)?

Comment: If the properties in the server are in xml format, it could be transformed to HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSP is a servlet with a different syntax. It executes at server-side. HTML5 is a markup language interpreted by browsers, at-client-side. It has nothing to do with reading properties files.

Since JSPs are servlets, they can contain any kind of Java code. So you read a properties file in a JSP the same way you would do it in any Java application (using the `java.util.Properties` class).

However, in well-designed applications, the JSP is only used as a view, generating markup from data prepared by a controller written in Java. It's the job of the controller to read a properties file. Not the job of a JSP.

I think you should read tutorials and understand what a servlet, a JSP, an HTML page, and MVC are, because you seem quite confused.